# bootstrap-combobox.js v1.0.0 change value with js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using this combobox. but cant change the value with js.

```
 $("#teacher_relay_county_combo").val("Value....");
 $("#teacher_relay_county").val("3");
```

None of the above have any effect when if I include it in my js file. If I run the same command the chrome developer tool console the value is changed. So what can be the reason?

Comment: At what time do you run the above? It sounds to me like a timing issue. That you're trying to set the value, before the element exists. Try to do `console.log($("#teacher_relay_county_combo").length)` and  `console.log($("#teacher_relay_county").length)` prior to setting the values and see if it writes 0 to the Chrome DevTools Console.

Comment: I didnt develop this from the start so I am not understanding how everything is put together. It is included in a compiled handlebars file. I have done this  console.log($("#teacher_relay_county_combo").length) and it returns 1. That made me even more confused.

Comment: Well, to help you must provide more details. Some code, a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

This one was called after i have set the value.

```
$("#teacher_relay_county").data('combobox').refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#teacher_relay_county").combobox("refresh");
```